# How to set custom brightness as default in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: brightness

My problem is whenever I boot the PC Ubuntu is loaded with full brightness... So every time I have to reduce brightness on booting and then start my work... So is there a way to set custom brightness to default so that I don't have to reduce brightness every time... Thanks for help...

Comment: No it's not duplicate... Link shows the person is not able to increase our decrease screen brightness... While I can perfectly increase our decrease screen brightness... No problem with that... But I have to decrease brightness every time I boot into Ubuntu as it loads with full brightness every time...

Comment: what is output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/`

Comment: output is like this acpi_video0  intel_backlight